# The doInBackground method is showing error in catlog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

LOG FILE :

```
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726): Process: com.example.pr, PID: 11726
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at com.example.pr.MainActivity$UploadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:137)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at com.example.pr.MainActivity$UploadImage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-18 20:27:09.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11726):    ... 4 more
```

When I'm trying to hit the Upload button the app crashes. Dont know whats happening.Below is my MainAcyivity.java

There is also an error in the php file that shows the warning of `file_put_contents`. Is that related to this?

In the `onClick(VIew v)` method I've created a constructor of `UploadImage` as -- `new UploadImage(image,text1.getText().toString()).execute()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final int RESULT_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://swapnil1.host22.com/";
ImageView image1,image2;
EditText text1,text2;
Button b1,b2;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
        text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.image1:

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_IMAGE);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selecting Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.button1:
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            new UploadImage(image,text1.getText().toString());

            UploadImage UI = new UploadImage();
            UI.execute();

            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            break;




        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImage);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
    private class  UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        Bitmap image;
        String name;

        public UploadImage(Bitmap image, String name)
        {

            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;

        }

        public UploadImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        @Override
            protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",encodedImage));


            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "upload.php");



            try
            {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);


            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}


private HttpParams  getHttpRequestParams()
{


    HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,1000 * 30);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,1000 * 30);
    return httpRequestParams;
}

}
```

Comment: In the logcat you can see the error is **NullPointerException**...please check the **line no 137 inside doInBackground**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the

```
new UploadImage(image,text1.getText().toString());

 UploadImage UI=new UploadImage();
 UI.execute();
```

to

```
       UploadImage UI=new UploadImage(image,text1.getText().toString());
       UI.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using constructor without arguments:

```
UploadImage UI=new UploadImage();
```

Which doesn't set the

```
Bitmap image;
```

field.

That's why you get NullPointerException on line:

```
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
```